# How do I make a multi-connection data load atomic?

Tags: python, connection-pooling, python-2.6, atomic, amazon-redshift

I am writing a fancy application in Python that loads a bunch of data from S3 into a Redshift cluster. The application issues a bunch of DDL against several tables if necessary, then loads the data into those tables via several `COPY` statements.

To make this whole process run as quickly as possible, I've made use of the back-ported [`futures` module](https://code.google.com/p/pythonfutures/) and [psycopg2's `ThreadedConnectionPool`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/pool.html#psycopg2.pool.ThreadedConnectionPool) to distribute the DDL and load activity across several connections in parallel.

It seems to work well. Now I want to make this whole process atomic.

The work being done is very straightforward. There is no potential for deadlocks since any given table is going to be altered and then loaded exactly once. Furthermore, it's OK to lock resources for the duration of the load. Finally, Redshift [supports transactions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_BEGIN.html) for all the activity I'm interested in. So in theory, what I want to do should be possible.

Right now the options I see are:

1. Somehow implement ghetto equivalents of `ThreadedConnectionPool.commitall()` and `ThreadedConnectionPool.rollbackall()`. (These methods don't exist, unfortunately.)
2. Look at ZODB's [transaction machinery](http://zodb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/transactions.html), which looks like overkill for my purposes.
3. Roll my own way of rolling back a partial load.
4. Give up on the multi-threaded approach and do everything on a single connection.

Is there a better way to do this that I've missed? None of these options look great.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want using the two-phase commit protocol.

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#two-phase-commit-protocol-support

...if it is supported by the server, which I doubt.